# NSTimer with CFRunLoop

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am having a strange issue. My NSTimer CallMe method does not get fired without CFRunLoop. And if I add CFRunLoop then the line after CFRunLoop never gets called. I want both the line after CFRunLoop and CallMe method to get fired.

EDIT - I dont care about CFRunLoop just want the the timer to fire every 20 secs.

I have added the code and the comments below

```
int main(int argc, char * const argv[]) {
Updater *theUpdater = [[Updater alloc] init];
NSTimer *theTimer = [theUpdater getTimer];
[theTimer retain];
//CFRunLoopRun();
 NSLog(@"I am here"); //If I uncomment CFRUnLoop this line does not get executed
}
```

@implementation Updater

```
- (NSTimer *)getTimer {
NSLog(@"Timer started");
NSTimer *theTimer;
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0
                                                target:self 
                                      selector:@selector(CallMe:) 
                                         userInfo:nil 
                                         repeats:YES];

return theTimer;
```

}

```
-(void) CallMe:(NSTimer*)theTimer{
NSLog(@"I Never get called");
}
```

@end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer needs to be created in the context of your CFRunLoop. So your code should look more like this:

```
NSRunLoop* myRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

Updater * theUpdater = [[Updater alloc] init];

[myRunLoop run]
```

You should have the *Updater* object retain your timer, since it is its owner. Note that when you invoke the *run* function that it will never terminate. For other options consult the [NSRunLoop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. From the `CFRunLoop` docs (emphasis added):

> `CFRunLoopRun`
>
> Runs the current thread’s CFRunLoop object in its default mode
>   **indefinitely**.

In other words, `CFRunLoopRun()` never returns, unless you call `CFRunLoopStop()` somewhere.